AWS DMS Error: "Invalid secretManagerAccessRoleArn" when using Secrets Manager role
Invalid secretManagerAccessRoleArn 'arn:aws:iam::069751638693:role/dms-migration-secrets-role-manual' for SecretManager
I've created an IAM role with the following:

Trust Policy:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "dms.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}


Attached Policies:


SecretsManagerReadWrite

AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole

AmazonDMSVPCManagementRole


I'm trying to use this role to allow DMS to access database credentials stored in Secrets Manager, but keep getting this error when creating/configuring the DMS task.
What am I missing in the role configuration? How can I resolve this error?
Environment:
AWS Region: us-west-2

Using AWS Console for configuration
Database credentials are stored in Secrets Manager
Trying to set up a new DMS migration task

Things I've already tried:

Created role with correct trust policy for DMS

Attached necessary policies including SecretsManagerReadWrite

Verified the role ARN is correct



Have you tried this using the region such as dms..amazonaws.com?
